# junit openapi - errors while integrating using springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

trying to get the JUnit to work with openAPI
( tried the example on this page
https://www.hascode.com/2018/08/testing-openapi-swagger-schema-compliance-with-java-junit-and-assertj-swagger/ )
but getting below errors.

```
public void validateThatImplementationMatchesDocumentationSpecification() {
    String apiContract = RestApiSchemaIntegrationTest.class.getResource("/swagger-contract.yaml").getPath();
    System.out.println(apiContract);
    String swaggerSchemaUrl = String.format("http://localhost:%d/v2/api-docs", port);
    SwaggerAssertions.assertThat(swaggerSchemaUrl)
        .isEqualTo(apiContract);
  }
}
```

## but getting below errors..

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
20:16:32.658 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '***ommunicationPersistanceConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '***tConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '*****Config': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
```

Comment: Whatever that autowired dependency is, it's not being properly injected in your test. Check your @InjectMocks annotations.